# When to clear the cache in Symfony 2 / 3 / 4

Tags: php, symfony, caching, yaml

#### Question

When exactly do you need to run the following command in Symfony 2 / 3 / 4?

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

---

#### Background

I thought it needed to be done when :

- adding / removing / modifying Twig files
- adding / removing / modifying YAML files

However, I've just changed a version number in a YAML configuration file, in an old Symfony 2 app, and the new version number showed up in my browser without clearing the Symfony cache (I'm not using the "app_dev.php" front controller).

Now, that YAML file (let's call it "app/config/data.yml") was loaded like this, in a controller:

```
$data = Yaml::parse($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/config/data.yml');
```

and is not included in other YAML files.

So, I guess in this case it isn't necessary to clear the cache?

Also, are there other things that require clearing the cache? Like adding a new bundle?

Comment: I'm also not 100% sure when you need to run `assets:install` and `assetic:dump`, but I should probably ask a separate question for that.

Comment: I'm almost entirely sure you need to clear cache when you change .yml file's `destination` rather than `content`. In case of JMS serializer and Symfony 3.4 I'm 100% sure of this. It's most likely the same with other yml using modules. Probably Twig too.